# Test observable return value of method with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Jasmine and I am attempting to write a simple unit test that checks if my method returns the intended value.  Here is the method in my Angular application:

```
saveEvent(techEvent): Observable<IEvent>{

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})

        return this.http.post('/api/events', techEvent, options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                //have an updated copy of saved event
                return response.json()
            }).catch(this.handleError)  
}
```

As you can see, it is a post method that saves a 'techEvent' object.  Here is the test I have attempted to write in my spec:

```
   it('should save the event', () => {

        var testEvent = { id: 7, name: "AngularJS"}

        mockHttp.post.and.returnValue(Observable.of(false))

        techEventService.saveEvent(<IEvent>testEvent)

        expect(techEventService.saveEvent).toBe(jasmine.any(Object))

    })
```

This test fails :( . My goal here is to simply test that the method returns an object and returns the specific object that is passed.  I wonder if I could also test if it is a JSON...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is asynchronous, which is generally the case for Observables.  You'll want to subscribe to the response from `techEventService.saveEvent` and verify that the variable was changed within that subscribe callback.

Additionally, you're testing whether `techEventService.saveEvent` is an object, but that is most definitely a reference to the `techEventService.saveEvent` function.  I believe you wanted to test if the response from the server was an object, which is another reason to run your test within the subscribe() callback.

```
it('should save the event', (done) => {

    var testEvent = { id: 7, name: "AngularJS"};

    mockHttp.post.and.returnValue(Observable.of(false));

    techEventService.saveEvent(<IEvent>testEvent).subscribe((response) => {
       expect(response).toBe(jasmine.any(Object));
       done();
    });
});
```

Because this is async, jasmine might think the test is done before your callback is actually loaded (never even reaching the `expect` call, and declaring your test a pass without having run it.)  For that reason, you can pass in `done` into your test, and then jasmine won't consider your test to have completed until you call the `done()` callback.

Side note: Make a habit of ending lines with semicolons when appropriate.

Comment: That makes prefect sense!  I wanted to test that the response is an object, not the method itself.  I do get an error I have never seen before when running this test however...

Error at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:9878node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:42) [<root>]
     at <anonymous> [<root>]

Comment: Make sure you have the following lines in your test.ts: require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy-zone'); // since zone.js 0.6.14
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch'); // put here since zone.js 0.6.14

Comment: I need clarification as I am not sure what test.ts is exactly.  Is that my spec file where i'm writing the test itself, like eventservice.spec.ts?  Is the the karma config or shim file...or somewhere in jasmine core? My zone.js is 0.8.4

Comment: P.S this is what I have in my karma.conf.js 

 // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

Comment: in my project, test.ts is under `\src\test.ts`.  It is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

Comment: I think I found the problem.  My path looks like this http://localhost:9878node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:42)
There is a slash missing.  Is this an issue in karma.conf